# Parameter remains null, even when I type it in URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So I have this method in a controller that I call through javascript but I get an error 500: Internal Server Error. When I try to go to the method directly through my URL, to see where the problem resided, I saw that the parameter is always passed as null.

Code is below:

Controller (parameter for EditTimeBeforeIdle should be a regular int but I changed it temporarily for debugging purposes):

```
[Authorize]
public class IdleController : BafcareController
{
    private readonly ISystemUnitOfWork _systemUnitOfWork;
    private readonly ICurrentUser _currentUser;

    private readonly User _user;

    public IdleController(ISystemUnitOfWork systemUnitOfWork, ICurrentUser currentUser)
    {
        _systemUnitOfWork = systemUnitOfWork;
        _currentUser = currentUser;

        _user = _systemUnitOfWork.UserRepository.GetUserById(_currentUser.User.Id); 
    }
    public int EditTimeBeforeIdle(int? time)
    { //<-- Breakpoint here to check, time == null

        _user.TimeBeforeIdle = time;
        _systemUnitOfWork.UserRepository.Update(_user);

        ModelSessionHelper.TimeBeforeIdle = time.Value;
        return time.Value;
    }
}
```

}

The URL I go to directly is

> http://localhost:4891/Idle/EditTimeBeforeIdle/21

So as you can see the parameter should not be null, so why is it?

Kind regards

Comment: How have you configured your routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or use the url:

```
 http://localhost:4891/Idle/EditTimeBeforeIdle/?time=21
```

Which is probably the way you want to do it.

Comment: Nah... No good programmer is born without a good brainfart now and then

Comment: But I have those quite often :-p

Answer (score 1):

rename the parameter to id.

This is the default binding  "{controller}/{action}/{id}" in MVC